# how to track max/min values for the last minute?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to create such class:

```
public TrackMaxMin(int periodInSec)

// use current system time as time
public Add(decimal value)

// return maximum Value for the last periodInSec
public Max { get {} }

// return minimum Value for the last periodInSec
public Min { get {} }
```

I think I can use FIFO query to store `Pair<DateTime, decimal`> and on each `Add` call I should:

- remove "outdated" values from query. when removing "update" cached Max/Min if needed
- add new value. update Max/Min if needed

My solution is trivial and straightforward. Probably you can suggest something better?

Comment: You can use [Queue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.100)) as a base storage to build you class

Comment: _"trivial and straightforward"_ are characteristics of good approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `max-heap` called `max`, a `min-heap` called `min`, and a `queue` called `q`.

Let `x` be an element with the properties `x.time` and `x.val`.

When `Add` is called:

- `Create` a new element `x`.
- `Add` `x` to all of the data structures.

The running time of `Add` is `O(lgn)`.

When `Max` is called:

- `max.GetMax()`

The running time of `Max` is `O(1)`.

When `Min` is called:

- `min.GetMin()`

The running time of `Min` is `O(1)`.

For the maintenance of the model do this:

Have only one timer that is fired each time the period of the next to go out element in `q` is due.

When the period of `x` is due then:

- `q.Dequeue()`, `max.Delete(x)`, `min.Delete(x)`

Comment: the only issue that I have to have constant `O(log n)` addition. I currently using trivial approach. Add is O(1). Min/Max is O(1) in most cases, O(n) in worst case and O(logn) in average.

Comment: O(lgn) in most cases is like O(1), then again maybe using 3 data structures is an over kill for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can store each pair in a queue. You should keep the data around for at least a minute, and then when Add is called you delete the stale data.

However, you should calculate Max and Min on the fly by looping through the stack data, or else you have lost data integrity.

Comment: i really think `queue` should be used here, not `stack`, as i need to clean-up oldest values. Also Max/Min need to be recalculated only when values updates. In most cases Max/Min doesn't change.

Comment: You said you want to track min and max for the last minute, so if you had a max value 90 seconds ago of 100 and a max value 45 seconds ago of 50, then Max() should return 50, right? That would require a calculated field.

Answer (score -1):

This is handy,

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
s.Start();
s.Stop();
long elapsedms = s.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: so you suggest storing `Stopwatch` for each item? But it's also easy to calculate difference between `DateTime` and current time...

Comment: Why would the stopwatch help anything?

Comment: Yes, its very easy to calculate time elapsed which is objective. If you believe alternate way is handy then its worth to use it rather than our own coding.. :)